# Specify default DB schema for SCDF server

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to force SCDF tables (batch and tasks) to be created **not** in default DB schema, the SCDF-CF with Postrgres bounded service is deployed with below manifest :

```
applications:
- name: data-flow-server
  memory: 2G
  disk_quota: 2G
  instances: 1
  buildpack: java_buildpack
  path: spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry-1.3.0.M3.jar
  env:
    SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME: data-flow-server
    SPRING_DATASOURCE_TOMCAT_CONNECTION-PROPERTIES: currentSchema=data-flow
  services:
    - myPostgresServiceName
```

All the tables are created in default schema, looks like autoconfiguration disregards the connection properties being set... please advise.

Thanks

Comment: On Cloud foundry, Dataflow will use the connection from the service to infer the schema, that's how service binding works in CF. So whatever schema is set for that service is what will be used.

Comment: And there is no way to specify the connection properties in addition to uri, username, password and db_name ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add more connection properties for sure using boot's `spring.datasource`. I'm not sure if the cloud connectors will pick that up. That is a different question

Comment: I'm already adding environment variable `SPRING_DATASOURCE_TOMCAT_CONNECTION-PROPERTIES: currentSchema=data-flow` without success ...

Comment: You need to wrap any and all `datasource` properties via `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` (it needs to be a well-formed JSON), only then it will take into account. It _cannot_ be a flat property like how you're supplying it right now.